# Adding a unique post number ID to Wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I want to add a counter to my Wordpress website. Each post has an id, but it tends to be a long, random number. I want a 1, 2, 3, 4 ... counter on each post that I can show next to a title/paragraph.

HTML - single.php

```
get_header(); ?>

    <main role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
        <?php bnNav_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    </main>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

HTML content-single

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post-content"> 

  <div class="row post-text-wrap">

    <div class="counter"> *** counter number here ***  </div>       

      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

        ...
```

Not sure where to start to accomplish this

EDIT

By counter I mean the the first post would display 1, second post would display 2, etc. (The post id does not output simple numbers like that)

I would like it to output to look like the following

1 / post title

text ....

Comment: Could you explain more what the counter should count exactly ? Its not clear from the question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a custom fields and enter in that field the number you want to be displayed near the title.

Follow the docs here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

You could add custom fields through this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

The code to display your custom field will look something like:

```
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?> | <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_post_number,ber' ); ?></h1>
```